# Store an array of 2 values on an array nodejs mongoose JOI

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, joi

i try to store a an array of 2 value on an array. I use mongoose for the model and JOI for the validation.

Here my code:

on my model:

```
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    detailsSheet: {
        type: [String]
    }
});

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);

const validateArticle = (article) => {
    const schema = {
        detailsSheet: Joi.array(),
    };
    return Joi.validate(article, schema);
};
```

on my route

```
routerArticles.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const {error} = validateArticle(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    const {detailsSheet} = req.body;
    let article = new Article({detailsSheet});
    article = await article.save();

    res.send(article);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's ok I found the solution. Very simple :

```
const Article = mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);

const validateArticle = (article) => {
    const schema = {
        detailsSheet: Joi.array().items(Joi.array())
    };
    return Joi.validate(article, schema);
};
```